# How do I properly point to array/job files within a PBS script?

Tags: python, unix, pbs

In advance, I sincerely apologize for such an elementary question, which may have already been answered. I am grateful for your help or for pointing me in the direction of an existing answer.

I am trying to run 1000 python scripts over 1000 data files by setting up an array job in a PSB script. Each script calls a specific data file explicitly; it's hardwired. It would be challenging here and unnecessary to explain why the python scripts and the data files need to be maintained separately.

I have python files names 1.py, 2.py, ... 1000.py. These are not stored in my home directory, and I think that's the problem now.

I have tried many many variations on the PBS script to no avail, but I am closer than I was this morning, I think.

In any case, here is what I have now:

```
#! /bin/bash
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -o TEST-ARRAY.txt    
#PBS -N TEST-ARRAY    
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PSB -t 1-1000%100
#PBS -q long  

file='SOME/DIRECTORY/'${PBS_ARRAYID}'.py'
python $file
```

Unfortunately, I get the error

```
python: can't open file 'SOME/DIRECTORY/.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So, it seems that my setting of the file variable is flawed, and the job array number cannot be inserted for the file name string. However, I have tried with and without single quotes, and several other logical things with no luck.

Thank you so kindly in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried changing "SOME/DIRECTORY/" to the actual directory where the files are? "SOME/DIRECTORY" is only a placeholder and needs to be changed to the real path.

Comment: Yes, of course. I only used "SOME/DIRECTORY/" here because the actual name is quite long and visually horrific.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I cannot pass

```
 ${PBS_ARRAYID}'.py'
```

to python. I should have noticed that the other models of arrays are

```
 somescript ${PBS_ARRAYID}.file
```

Where the script is the same among all jobs and the data files vary. This was not my case.

I solved this problem in a newbie way by making many scheduler files. Yeah, one for each of the 1000 jobs.... And then running the qsub command over all of them to create the array. So, the final line in my PBS script looked like this:

```
 qsub ${PBS_ARRAYID}.sh
```

I understand that I could have looped over the scheduler script without having to actually make 1000 scripts, but I could get that to work quite right and will try it again later.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. The problem seems to be "${PBS_ARRAYID}" on our server. Oh well. So, ignore my answer here.